# sum function based on unique date

Tags: mysql

actually i want a total value based on unique date

```
SELECT t2.stateName,
t3.`districtName`,t1.fingerDate,COUNT(a.arg1),COUNT(a.arg2),COUNT(a.arg3),COUNT(a.arg4),COUNT(a.arg5),COUNT(a.arg6),COUNT(a.arg7), COUNT(a.arg8),(COUNT(a.arg1) + COUNT(a.arg2) + COUNT(a.arg3) + COUNT(a.arg4) + COUNT(a.arg5) + COUNT(a.arg6) + COUNT(a.arg7))AtotalScreeningArg
FROM tbl_user AS t1
LEFT JOIN tbl_state AS t2 ON t1.addressState = t2.stateId 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_district` AS t3 ON t1.addressDistrict = t3.`districtId` 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT userId,
CASE WHEN occupation = "Truckers" OR occupation = "Drivers" 
THEN occupation END arg1,
CASE WHEN (occupation = "Migrant") 
THEN occupation END arg2, 
CASE WHEN (hrg IS NULL OR hrg = " ") AND (`arg` IS NULL OR `arg` = " ") 
THEN "Student" END arg3,
CASE WHEN (occupation = "Daily Wage") 
THEN occupation END arg4, 
CASE WHEN (occupation = "Salaried" OR occupation = "self Employed" OR occupation ="Unemployed" OR occupation = "Other") 
THEN occupation END arg5, 
CASE WHEN (ARG = "Female Partner (FPHRG)" OR ARG = "Partner / Spouse of FSW") 
THEN ARG END arg6,CASE WHEN ARG = "Female Partner (FPARG)" THEN ARG END arg7,
CASE WHEN ARG = "TG (F-M)" THEN ARG END arg8,CASE WHEN hrg = "MSM" THEN hrg END arg9,
CASE WHEN hrg = "TG(M_F)" THEN hrg END arg10,CASE WHEN hrg = "FSW" THEN hrg END arg11,CASE WHEN hrg = "IDU" THEN hrg END arg12 FROM `tbl_user`
WHERE fingerDate IS NOT NULL OR fingerDate != " ")a ON t1.userId = a.userId
WHERE `t1`.`deleted` = "N" AND t1.userType = "user" AND `t1`.`fingerDate` >= '2018-11-01' AND `t1`.`fingerDate` <= '2018-12-01' AND t1.addressState = '34' AND t1.addressDistrict = '614' GROUP BY t1.userId
```

it gives result but not for unique date

Comment: Most likely it wil give invalid results as the is generally not the use the use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) *"SQL-92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause."*  there is a execption in SQL 1992 which is called  [functionally dependent](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) which MySQL 5.7.5+ supports

Comment: Actually i like data according to unique date which is based on fingerDate and i used group by based on userId when i replace userId by fingerDate in group by clause it solves up my problem thanks

Comment: if you don't have atleast MySQL 5.7.5+ you can't trust functionally dependency to make one thing clear..